# JNI native functions v/s java functions call sequence

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to create JNI functions inside a java class along with java functions in same class.

Below are the codes of three files created

1) Class containing the java functions:

```
package org.jnp.pkg001;

public class HelloNative {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("lib/HelloNativeLib");
    }
    public native void cprintLineOne ();
    public native void cprintLineTwo ();

    public void jprintLineOne ()
    {
        System.out.println("Hi, I am in Java First Function");
    }

    public void jprintLineTwo ()
    {
        System.out.println("Hi, I am in Java Second Function");
    }
}
```

2) Native functions implementation:

```
#include "org_jnp_pkg001_HelloNative.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_jnp_pkg001_HelloNative_cprintLineOne
  (JNIEnv *, jobject)
{
    printf("Hi, I am in C First Function\n");
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_jnp_pkg001_HelloNative_cprintLineTwo
  (JNIEnv *, jobject)
{
    printf("Hi, I am in C Second Function\n");
}
```

3) Java class containing the main

```
package test.jnp.pkg001;

import org.jnp.pkg001.HelloNative;

public class HelloNativeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HelloNative hn= new HelloNative();
        hn.cprintLineOne();
        hn.jprintLineOne(); 
        hn.cprintLineTwo();
        hn.jprintLineTwo();

    }

}
```

I got the output as below, which is not matching the sequence in which the functions were called

```
Hi, I am in Java First Function
Hi, I am in Java Second Function
Hi, I am in C First Function
Hi, I am in C Second Function
```

Can anyone tell me why this sequence is not matching the function call sequence? and suggest a solution over it.

Comment: They're called methods... You're not flushing the stream in C and both are printing to the same TTY, I suspect this is the issue.

Comment: I suspect you need to flush the C stream.

Comment: `printf()` doesn't `fflush(stdout)`, you need the latter in the C code (since `stdout` seems to be buffered)